# Can MVC Views be transformed for multiple deployements like web.config files can?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In one of my MVC projects, I have a special configuration setup for a test deployment site.  Doing this, I was able to add a config tranformation to override various settings in my web.config file.  For example, I have the following files:

```
web.config
web.release.config
web.debug.config
web.testsite.config
```

When I deploy to my test site, it now overwrites some settings specified in my web.testsite.config

Is it possible to get the same behavior on some of my views?  For example, could I have a Index.testsite.cshtml?  I could toggle behavior on and off with flags from the configuration, however it seems like a cleaner approach would be to allow for additional transformations/replacement views based on configuration.

Comment: How would `Index.testsite.cshtml` override some code in `Index.cshtml`? based on what syntax (no xml transformations involved)? or maybe you just want MVC to use `Index.testsite.cshtml` when in `test` environment?

Comment: Yeah, my thought would be a full replacement when this feature is used.  So if I'm publishing a build using the "testsite" configuration, it would know to use the testsite version of Index.cshtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually easy to do.

*global.asax - Inside Application_Start()*

```
var displayModes = DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes;
displayModes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("TestSite")
    {
        ContextCondition = (context => IsTestSite())
    });
```

*Definition of IsTestSite()*

```
public bool IsTestSite()
{
    bool isTestSite;
    return bool.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["isTestSite"], out isTestSite);
}
```

That's it, now your app will use `Intex.TestSite.cshtml` if present otherwise it will serve `Index.cshtml`. The same holds true for any other view name as well, just stick `TestSite` before the extension.

Comment: No problem, it's intended to allow you to use alternate display modes based off browser capabilities, like having a DisplayMode for Phones or Tablets or more specicifcally for IE or Safari if you wanted. But I find it's just as useful for things like showing an alternate view based off development environment, or other context specific data. For example a public user might get a different view than an employee. I don't know what the security aspect of this method is like, but this is just the presentation layer anyway. All of the server side code should have redundant security checks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your `Base/Controller`:

```
protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;

    if (viewResult != null)
    {
        string env = ... // determine your environment somehow

        var razorEngine = viewResult.ViewEngineCollection.OfType<RazorViewEngine>().Single();
        var viewName = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(viewResult.ViewName) ? viewResult.ViewName : filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        var razorView = razorEngine.FindView(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, viewName, viewResult.MasterName, false).View as RazorView;
        var currentPath = razorView.ViewPath;
        var newPath = currentPath.Replace(".cshtml", env + ".cshtml");

        if (razorEngine.FileExists(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, newPath))
            viewResult.View = new RazorView(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, newPath, razorView.LayoutPath, razorView.RunViewStartPages, razorView.ViewStartFileExtensions);
    }

    base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Also, if you're using MVC 4 (hence `WebPages` 2.0), you can use `DisplayModeProvider` to achieve this easily.

In your `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Add(new DefaultDisplayMode("debug")
        {
            ContextCondition = (context => context.IsDebuggingEnabled)
        });

        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Add(new DefaultDisplayMode("test")
        {
            ContextCondition = (context => context.Request.IsLocal)
        });
     }
```

Comment: I couldn't get your 2nd method to work correctly, however it worked in Yarx's example.  +1 for the idea though!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to implement a custom action filter that checks your configuration setting and serves up the correct view based on its value.

Comment: I thought of something similar, but I was more curious to see if there is already some feature or best practice to accomplish this.  Having it in the code just seems like it could get messy after a while.  I was hoping to find a more organized / easy to spot approach.